# Create 3 dimensional array

Tags: c#, syntax, multidimensional-array

I'm new at C# and I want to create a multidimensional array like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [parks.ca.gov](http://kids.parks.ca.gov/pages/22784/images/maze.gif))</sub>

But in 8x8x4 cells.

I want to store maze cells.

```
{
    {1,1,1,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,1,1,1}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,1,0,1}, {1,1,0,1}, {0,1,0,0}, {1,0,0,1},
    ...
    {0,1,1,0}, {1,0,1,0}, {0,0,1,1}, {1,0,1,0}, {1,0,0,1}, {0,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,0}, {1,1,0,1},
}
```

```
int[,,] table = new int[8,8,4]; // is this right?

table[0,0] = {0, 0, 1, 1}; // I want to fill it this way.
```

Comment: We're in C#, not C, why not use some OO principles? Just create a list of classes named Cell that contain 3 properties. 3D arrays are such a mess when it's time to debug. It amaze me how people like to complicate things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm aware it does not *explicitly* answer the question, but in my opinion you're shooting yourself in the foot by working with 3D arrays. C# is an OO language, so it really helps if you think OO.

Instead of working with a multidimensional array representing cells for you 3d Maze (if it is really a 3d maze you want), why not create a `List` of classes named Cell, each one containing their position and other stuff you need, like :

```
public class Cell
{ 
    public Cell (int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
    public bool IsExplored { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have a simple `List<Cell>` that you can iterate over.
You can also remove the x,y,z and create a `Position` class.

For walls, you can create an `Enum` and use bitwise operations, or store a list of `Enum`. Since you're a beginner, I'd suggest you the list of enums. You would have to add this Enum in the code, and this property to the `Cell` class :

```
public Enum WallPosition
{
    Top,
    Left,
    Bottom,
    Right
}


public List<WallPosition> walls { get; set;} //This goes into the Cell class
```

That way, every operation will be much much easier to do. For example, if you need to explore every cell at the column #3, you can do

```
foreach (Cell cell in yourCellList.Where(c => c.Y == 3))
{
    cell.IsExplored = true;
}
```

Need to render every explored cell differently?

```
foreach (Cell cell in yourCellList.Where(c => c.IsExplored) { //Do stuff }
```

And so on.

No need for complicated `for` loops with your 3 dimensions, and a simple `foreach` is in my opinion far more readable than a

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
```

every time you need to access your table.

The only ugly part would be to fill you list (By creating new `Cell` instances), but it would still be far more readable than a huge wall of `{ {  { 0, 1, 0, 1 }, {1, 1, 1, 0} [...]`

I'd also suggest that you read an [introduction to OO principles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep).

Comment: “C# is an OO language, so it really helps if you think OO.” C# is a multi-paradigm language, so you should use whatever fits the task best. And I'm not sure can actually call using a type containing 4 simple values “OO”. You can easily do that in C or Haskell, and neither of them is OO.

Comment: Also, your design is incredibly slow, accessing a specific cell is O(n), compared with O(1) if you use multidimensional array. If you want to be able to use `foreach` easily, you can create helper method for that, without sacrificing performance.

Comment: @svick Incredibly slow? It's a 8x8x4 grid; 256 cells. You can bruteforce a whole sudoku grid (9 * 9 * 9 possibilities; 729 possibilities) in 5 to 15 ms with an appropriate design... I honestly don't think you have to sacrifice readability and maintainability for a few microseconds accessing a single cell.

Comment: I don't see how does using a multidimensional array sacrifice readability of maintainability. Like I said, if you want to use `foreach`, you can write a simple helper method for that. And this is not Sudoku, which will stay 9×9 forever (and I have absolutely no idea where did the number 729 come from, but that's not relevant here). The maze is 8×8 now, but it may easily become larger in the future.

Comment: @svick I did some benchmarks and, on my computer, to reach 300ms of execution time (the time to blink, in average) in getting the last element of the list, you need at least 15 000 000 elements. I think he could be fine with 256 cells. But still, you are right, after 60 000 calls on his list the execution would take just a bit longer than a blink, which is incredibly slow.

Answer (score 1):

1. With multidimensional arrays, you can either set them all at once (using basically the syntax you showed):

   ```
   int[,,] table = {
                     { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 0, 0 } },
                     { { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1, 0 } }
                   };
   ```

   or you can set the items one by one:

   ```
   int[,,] table = new int[8,8,4];
   table[0,0,0] = 0;
   ```

   there is nothing in between. The best you could do is to write an extension method that would work something like this:

   ```
   table.Set(0, 0, new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 });
   ```
2. As an alternative, you could use 2D array of arrays:

   ```
   int[,][] table = {
                     { new[] { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, new[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 } },
                     { new[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, new[] { 1, 0, 1, 0 } }
                   };
   ```

   or you could use almost the syntax you proposed:

   ```
   int[,][] table = new int[8,8][];
   table[0,0] = new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
   ```

   A disadvantage of this approach is that it doesn't force the inner arrays to be all the same length.
3. As proposed in comments, another option would be use a custom type like `Cell` and have a 2D array of those. Doing that makes it clearer what the array actually means, `table[0,0].Left` is certainly more readable than `table[0,0,1]`.
4. If the wall can be there or not, you shouldn't use `int` values `0` and `1`, you should use `bool` values `false` and `true`. If you want to have more states, an `enum` might be appropriate.
5. Your structure contains a lot of duplication, since bottom of a cell is the same as top of the cell below it (unless you want to have one way walls). This means the structure can get into an inconsistent state, which is often hard to debug (“The wall isn't there? But I just looked and it *is* there.”).

   One way to avoid that would be store walls instead of cells. Instead of 8×8 cells, you would have 8×9 horizontal walls and 9×8 vertical walls. You could then have methods that would abstract this away, so you could easily look up walls of a particular cell.

Answer (score 0):

An array initializer for a 3D array would look like this:

```
int[,,] table = {
                  { {1,1,1,0}, {1,0,0,0}, ... },
                  { {0,1,1,0}, {1,0,1,0}, ... },
                  ...
                };
```

The first line is right. The second line won't work. The closest thing is to use a 2D array of arrays:

```
int[,][] table = new int[8,8][];
table[0,0] = new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1};
```

Like @tigrou and @Pierre-Luc Pineault suggested, it would be a lot cleaner to encapsulate each cell in an object instead of a plain array.

Consider storing the data in an external file and reading it in instead of hardcoding the 256 numbers.

Comment: Your second snippet won't compile. 3D array is not 2D array of arrays, but you're trying to treat it like one.